# How can i find in java program, whether the given string is encrypted string or not?

Tags: java

For exmple, am giving the string like "u8tyuy8+==" (this is encrypted string using bouncy castle) to java..  i need to do validation like whether the given string is encrypted string or not? is there any method exist in java?

Comment: If you think it's encrypted, you can always try decrypting it.

Comment: i dont know how the incoming string will be from database. some data will be encrypted and some data wont. i need to decrypt, only if the incoming string has encrypted values.

Comment: I think what @Bucket is trying to say is to always try to decrypt it. if it's not a valid encrypted string, the decryption will fail. It's not the best, but it's pretty hard to find a pattern, unless you add some sort of prefix to the incoming string. something like `{encyption}u8tyuy8+==` and you decrypt only the ones that have that prefix. Not sure if you have control over that.

Comment: In that case your database will be better if it contains a column saying "encrypted", with `true` or `false` values (1 and 0 in databases that don't support boolean). And the application that writes to database will have to set that column.

Comment: @sfat Correct. There's no risk in attempting to decrypt if there's no unequivocal way to tell if it is encrypted.

Comment: If you know that it was encrypted in blockade (ECB, CBC, etc) then either the plain text was a multiple of the block size or it was padded. So first check to see if the data is a multiple of the block size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is theoretically impossible to say if a given String *has been* encrypted.  The best you could do would be to tell if it *could have been* encrypted.  Even then, it depends on knowing the encryption scheme(s) (and armoring<sup>1</sup> scheme(s)) that could have been used.

As RealSkeptic points out, a better approach would be to record (in your database) whether or not the string has been encrypted, and (if necessary) which schemes have been used for encrypting and armoring the data.

---

@Bucket comments:

> There's no risk in attempting to decrypt if there's no unequivocal way to tell if it is encrypted.

Yes, there is no risk in trying.  (Especially if you catch any possible exceptions.)  However, the flipside is that there is no unequivocal way of telling if you have *successfully* decrypted the string<sup>2</sup>, so there is not a lot to be achieved by doing this.

---

<sup>1 - I am guessing based on the example string that the original data has been encrypted, and then encoded as ASCII using Base64 encoding ... or something similar.</sup>

<sup>2 - ... unless you also have the original unencrypted version of the data to compare against.</sup>

Comment: Yes. You are right..  string encoded as ASCII using base64 encoding.. Ok..  then let me do decrypt for all the inputs.. if exception occurs, then will handle in catch block..

Comment: How will it be known is the file decrypted correctly, that a plain text file was not decrypted.

Comment: @zaph if am trying to decrypt with wrong key.. it will throw the padding exception...

Comment: Padding exceptions are not a true indicator, consider the data ending with a 0x01 byte, padding error or good data, can't tell.  Using padding errors to determine correct decryption is a common error and not all implementation report padding errors since padding errors can be used for a padding oracle attack that can reveal the data (except the first block). Additionally not all encryption modes use padding such as CTR, CTS, etc.